# set a value to a prop of a component that is passed in as another prop of its parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

(I am developing a react-native project)

I have a custom component which takes another custom component as its prop:

```
<MyCustomComponent
        data={mydata}
        optionalComponent={<MySubComponent />}
      />
```

`MySubComponent` looks like this:

```
const MySubComponent = ({car}) => {
   ...
}
export default MySubComponent;
```

As you can see above, this component has a `car` prop.

`MyCustomComponent` looks like this:

```
const MyCustomComponent = ({data, optionalComponent}) => {
   const myCar = getCar();
   // How can I set myCar to optionalComponent passed in here??
}
export default MyCustomComponent;
```

My question is in `MyCustomComponent`, how can I set `myCar` to the passed-in `optionalComponent` 's `car` prop ? (knowing it always has a `car` prop).

(Please don't suggesting moving `myCar` to uppper level then pass in as normal case. I wonder the possibilty my question is asking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the component's reference to the custom component like so:

```
<MyCustomComponent data={mydata} optionalComponent={MySubComponent} />
```

And re-assign the reference to a variable with an upper case:

```
const MyCustomComponent = ({ data, optionalComponent }) => {
   const MyCar= optionalComponent;
   // ..
   return <MyCar /* Add the required props here */ />
}
```

**Alternatively**, you can take advantage of the children prop but you'll have to wrap `MySubComponent` inside `MyCustomComponent` like so:

```
<MyCustomComponent data={mydata}>
  <MySubComponent /* Add the required props here */ />
</MyCustomComponent>
```

And in `MyCustomComponent`:

```
const MyCustomComponent = ({ data, children }) => {
   // ..
   return (
     <div>
       {/** other stuff */}
       {children}
       {/** other stuff */}
     </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want correctly then I think you're doing that backwards. The passed in component doesn't actually have any props, it only takes props when it's invoked but it hasn't been invoked yet. If you want both your components to use the same car prop then why not pass it to MyCustomComponent and have that component pass it down to MySubComponent? That's the normal react flow. Alternatively, you can use the context API and stores and hook up both components to the same store but It's not clear why you'd want that.

Is MyCustomComponent the component that's actually rendering the instance of MySubComponent whose car prop you want to get?